# How to initialize git without the global directory?

Tags: laravel, git, gitlab

I want to put my LARAVEL project from the git repository to my server, to do this I:

1. `git init`
2. `sudo git clone git@gitlab.com:test-name/my-project.git`

Now I have the following content:

```
drwxr-sr-x  4 ubuntu www-data   37 Mar 26 08:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x  6 root   root      101 Sep  5  2019 ../
drwxr-sr-x  7 root   www-data  119 Mar 26 08:53 .git/
drwxr-sr-x 12 root   www-data 4096 Mar 26 08:53 my-project/
```

and now when I list `my-project` I also see `.git\` directory !

But in fact I want the content of `my-project` directly, not inside `my-project` directory.

What should I do ?

Comment: Add dot at the end of the command.

**sudo git clone git@gitlab.com:test-name/my-project.git .**

Comment: Don't do `git init` before you clone.

Comment: @fredrik I did it ! how can I correct this  ?

Comment: @Poonkodi : if I remove everything and `sudo git clone git@gitlab.com:test-name/my-project.git .` it will correct this ?

Comment: Yes.
1. Create new folder - mkdir test
2. Go to the folder - cd test
3. Just clone the project - sudo git clone git@gitlab.com:test-name/my-project.git .

Comment: @MostafaAbdellaoui Is it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with the `git init` at all: `git clone` means:

1. Make a directory, and enter that directory, so that all of the remaining five steps occur in that directory.
2. Run `git init`.
3. Run `git remote add origin url`, where the *`url`* comes from the `git clone` argument.  You can change this name from `origin` to some other name, but you didn't.
4. Run any necessary `git config` operations (you didn't list any extra configurations to apply so this step doesn't do anything in your case).
5. Run `git fetch origin`.
6. Run `git checkout name`, where the *`name`* comes from the `-b` argument you gave to `git clone`.  You didn't give one, so instead, *`name`* comes from the recommendation that the other Git over at `origin` gives.  Most other Gits recommend `master`.

Note that step 2 does *its own* `git init`, so that's why you should not be doing one yourself.  (If you like, you can run all six steps yourself, one at a time.  Note that if you do that, you'll wind up in the directory you made.  When `git clone` makes the directory and enters it, that doesn't move *you*, so this is slightly different.)

(In general, you should not be running *any* Git command with `sudo`.  You might have some particular reason for doing that, but in general you should find some way to avoid doing that.)